# Securing Joomla against an ex-employee

Tags: security, joomla, joomla2.5

We've got a Joomla site that's been done by an ex-employee that has been modifying things they shouldn't be changing anymore. I've changed the FTP, DB and hosting CP passwords, changed all of the Joomla user account passwords, removed their user account and phpMyAdmin from the site.

I've no experience with Joomla so I'm just making sure that I've not missed out any other settings and that there's not a way of them resetting the password.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A strongly worded e-mail about the legality of changing a system he is no longer authorised to access probably is also required.

Comment: Perhaps this question is more suitable for http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: looks like you did everything right, until there is some kinds of backdoors, nobody could you tell without revise

Comment: Be sure to maintain all logs, security or otherwise, showing why you believe this ex-exmployee is still accessing and changing items.  Give this to your company lawyer.  I have zero patience for that type of crap and would pursue it to the point of seeing that person in court.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my knowledge what you can do is to change the Cpanel PW, FTP PW, Delete any user accounts which you have already done.

Except above check out error log and other log files if you have them and don't forget to take backups frequently just in case that person messed up everything.

Comment: Rather than delete the account you can also block the account and put it in a user group with no permissions.  The reason you wouldn't delete among other things is that if the person created content you are going to end up with sql problems at times unless you go though and change he created by and modified by fields.

Answer (score 0):

You have made the correct changes and they will now have no access to the Joomla admin panel or the FTP, however if the hosting account is registered in their name, then they still have the permission to simply close the account. In which case, I would strongly take a backup of the site and database. You could also install [Saxum IP Logger](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/analytics/visitors/8946) and blacklist their IP address for the administrator URL.